# No way to make works react native expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I just have this project: https://gitlab.com/BosatzuKannon/parking-app.git

I made the apk a year ago to the company, but now I have to make some changes and I just try to run "npx expo start" and there is no way to make it works!

Do you have any advide or way to make it works?

- Node: 14.15.1
- React Native: 0.64.3
- Expo: 44.0.0

It runs but when i scan the qr from my phone, I get this error:

```
Android Bundling failed 14158ms
Unable to resolve module @swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_get.cjs from C:\Users\Bosatzu\Desktop\aws\Blomi\testapp\parking-app-front-parking\parking-app-front-parking\node_modules\@react-aria\interactions\dist\main.js: @swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_get.cjs could not be found within the project or in these directories:

 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  1 | var $goTMa$reactariautils = require("@react-aria/utils");
  2 | var $goTMa$react = require("react");
> 3 | var $goTMa$swchelperscjs_class_private_field_getcjs = require("@swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_get.cjs");
    |                                                                ^
  4 | var $goTMa$swchelperscjs_class_private_field_initcjs = require("@swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_init.cjs");
  5 | var $goTMa$swchelperscjs_class_private_field_setcjs = require("@swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_set.cjs");
  6 | var $goTMa$reactariassr = require("@react-aria/ssr");
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.20.7",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "0.2.6",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "3.6.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.12.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.5",
    "@swc/helpers": "0.4.1",
    "axios": "0.21.4",
    "core-js": "3.20.3",
    "expo": "44.0.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "2.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "5.1.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "0.8.6",
    "expo-font": "10.0.4",
    "expo-location": "14.0.1",
    "expo-modules-core": "~0.6.4",
    "expo-splash-screen": "0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "0.11.7",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "native-base": "3.1.0",
    "qrcode": "1.5.0",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-air-progress-bar": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-backdrop": "2.1.2",
    "react-native-count-to": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "2.7.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "4.1.1",
    "react-native-dialog": "8.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-hide-show-password-input": "1.2.0",
    "react-native-ico": "28.7.4",
    "react-native-ico-material-design": "3.3.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
    "react-native-material-design": "0.3.7",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "13.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-propel-kit": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "3.10.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "2.4.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.9.1",
    "react-native-stars": "1.2.2",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "3.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "0.15.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "2.10.4",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "rn-qr-generator": "1.2.0",
    "sentry-expo": "4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "5.3.1",
    "styled-system": "5.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "parking-app-front",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

When I run the expo start and scan the qr from my phone, it shows me this:

```
Unable to resolve module @swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_get.cjs from C:\Users\Bosatzu\Desktop\aws\Blomi\testapp\parking-app-front-parking\parking-app-front-parking\node_modules\@react-aria\interactions\dist\main.js: @swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_get.cjs could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules\@react-aria\interactions\node_modules
  node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  1 | var $goTMa$reactariautils = require("@react-aria/utils");
  2 | var $goTMa$react = require("react");
> 3 | var $goTMa$swchelperscjs_class_private_field_getcjs = require("@swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_get.cjs");
    |                                                                ^
  4 | var $goTMa$swchelperscjs_class_private_field_initcjs = require("@swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_init.cjs");
  5 | var $goTMa$swchelperscjs_class_private_field_setcjs = require("@swc/helpers/cjs/_class_private_field_set.cjs");
  6 | var $goTMa$reactariassr = require("@react-aria/ssr");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just use the correct version of the expo go. 2.24.6

Answer (score 1):

Expo v44 is no longer under active support.

You didn't mention whether you re-installed the NPMs, and if you did whether you are getting the EXACT SAME versions you previously had (or did you get newer versions of some of them?).

Also, your project is mixing use of `react-native` for some commands and `expo` for others?  I would highly recommend moving entirely onto `expo`, and updating to the latest-n-greatest release.

Also `npx expo ....` will be using a much newer version of the Expo CLI than you had previously used. This is likely leading to an incompatibility between the Expo CLI (newer Expo) and your project (older/deprecated Expo).

Comment: Hello! Yes I use yarn to install the same versions that I used a year ago, using windows 10. Event de global expo-cli at the same version.

I try to upgrade all the modules but it was worst. Just erros everywhere

Comment: You will want to look at the release notes of each version since yours (v45, v46, ...) for the change notes, especially the "BREAKING CHANGES" sections.  With each release, Expo does a pretty good job explaining what issues you will run into with the upgrade.

"More errors" does not necessarily mean "further from success".  You could be stuck on just a single issue with your code on v44, but if that issue is only fixed in a newer version of Expo, then you are never going to get past it ;)